# gwt editor framework, copy the state of the ui into the object - best practices when persisting object

Tags: java, gwt

so, just wondering if this is even possible

i have been using the editor framework and am wondering if, instead of pushing the state of the object out to the ui using the edit calls - is there anyway you can take the state of the form and pump it into the object.

i am using a RequestFactoryEditorDriver with proxy objects and am trying to do something along the lines of a reverse-editor where i populate my proxy object with the values in the form and then persist it.

I am also new to GWT, i started 2 weeks ago and have been teaching myself off of various sample code and google, is there any other GWT framework to do this.  or, what are the best practices when simply persisting new objects?

i am using activities/places and up until just tonight (i am trying to get something out quick so i know it wasn't the correct way to do it) was passing in all the fields of the form through my presenter to create an object.  i would like to do something cleaner.

any help is greatly appreciated

---

to anybody else doing this - thomas broyer answered it and here is how i got this
activity to work

```
public class EmployeesCreateFormActivity extends AbstractActivity implements EmployeesCreateFormView.Presenter

  interface EmployeeEditorDriver extends RequestFactoryEditorDriver<EmployeeProxy, EmployeesCreateFormView> {
  }

  private final ClientFactory clientFactory;
  private final EmployeesCreateFormView view;

  private EmployeeRequestContext employeeContext;
  private EmployeeProxy employee;
  private final EmployeeEditorDriver editor;

  public EmployeesCreateFormActivity(ClientFactory clientFactory) {
    this.clientFactory = clientFactory;
    view = clientFactory.getEmployeesCreateFormView();

    employeeContext = clientFactory.getRequestFactory().employeeContext();
    employee = employeeContext.create(EmployeeProxy.class);
    editor = GWT.create(EmployeeEditorDriver.class);
  }

  @Override
  public void start(AcceptsOneWidget container, EventBus eventBus) {
    view.setPresenter(this);
    container.setWidget(view.asWidget());
    editor.initialize(view);
    editor.edit(employee, employeeContext);
  }

  @Override
  public void doCreate() {
    editor.flush();
    // I STILL HAVE NO IDEA WHAT TO DO WITH THIS ????????
    employee.setVersion(Integer.valueOf(1));

    Request<EmployeeProxy> createRequest = employeeContext.persist(employee);
    createRequest.fire(new Receiver<EmployeeProxy>() {

      @Override
      public void onSuccess(EmployeeProxy response) {
        Window.alert("successfully created employee " + response.getId() + ": " + response.getFirstName());
        clientFactory.getPlaceController().goTo(new EmployeesCreatePlace());
        }
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to do it is to `edit()` an empty object (e.g. one that you just created) when your activity starts (just like if you were editing an existing object), so that the `flush()` will populate the object with the fields' values.

Comment: thank you for the answer - if you don't mind i have a question though as i'm not really sure how to do this.  Currently when i try this i'm getting the exception "attempting to edit an entity proxy previously edited by another request context" which makes sense.  What i'm wondering though is if there is a proper way to layout the Activity so that this does not happen.

Comment: What i have done in my activity is the following: i hold a reference to an EmployeeProxy - then on the start method i use my client factory to get the appropriate RequestContext and create the employeeProxy.  I then do as you mentioned and call edit() with the employee proxy and calling requestFactory.employeeContext again.

Comment: In my onCreate method (which i'm not sure if i'm doing it right - my activity is a presenter and i call the presenter.onCreate) i simply call editor.flush() and try to persist it at which time the error is thrown.  Also, I have been reading your blog for the last 2 weeks i've been doing this - i was wondering if anywhere in there you have a correct example of how to do this.  If you have these answers I greatly appreciate it. Thank you very much

Comment: sorry about the multiple comments

Comment: The proxy has to be created and persisted with the same context.